# Display css none is not working in IE 8,9 on @media (max-width:786px){}

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to display none a div on `@media (max-width:786px){}`
I want to fix with jquery `.hide()` function. What will be the possible code?

Comment: [It should work on IE 9](http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have in mind that media queries are not compatible with IE8.
Take a look at [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) for IE8 compatibility.

Better approach is using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to detect media queries compatibility and then using jquery `.hide()` when you need it :

```
if(!Modernizr.mq('only all') && $(window).width() < 786){
  // Hide your element with jquery .hide();    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not a direct answer to your question, but this library convert your mediaqueries for browser that does not support it:

https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/

Just load it and it does all the job.

Comment: this one also very usefull